# How to submit a form that has no class/id defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create some chat binds for a website that'd help me with communication. I ran into a problem where there's no submit button in the chat nor the submit() function isn't working.

```
$(".Chat__formInner [placeholder='Type your message here to chat...']").submit()
$(".Chat__formInner form textarea")[0].submit()
$(".Chat__formInner form textarea").submit()
```

I've also tried simulating the Enter keypress on the input area but it doesn't trigger the submit function either.

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keypress")
e.which = 13
e.keyCode = 13
$(".Chat__formInner form").trigger(e)
```

[image]

Comment: I don't see any action attribute on the form

Comment: should be `$(".Chat__formInner form textarea").submit()`->`$(".Chat__formInner form").submit()`

Comment: @Keatinge - it's CSGOStrong.com, but you need a Steam account to access the HTML content of the chat as far as I'm concerned. I'm a chat moderator there, so I cannot really do anything for you to be able to access the site without logging into the site.

Comment: @Gautam Jha, this just reloads the page from the server for some reason...

Comment: @Eomm, it's external apparently
return function(e) {
  return e.preventDefault(), t.call(this, e)
}

Comment: @Keatinge Oh, don't worry you can. A message saying that you should log in will pop-up if the message is submitted correctly

Answer (score 1):

Okay, there is my trickz :
It should have better way to do it, but this will work for you i think

```
$("textarea").keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var el = $( "<input hidden type='submit'>");
        $(".Chat__formInner form").append(el);
    el.click().remove();
  }
})
```

Here the [LIVE DEMO JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8m2633Lh/)

Comment: I saw that already, but it isn't working when pasted into the console, which is what I want to do

Comment: You want an external script for trigger a send message ?

Comment: Yes, I'm setting up some keybinds that'd let me send messages quickly without typing them over and over again, this is why I need an external script

Comment: <input type="submit"> - One question, what do I need to do to trigger a click() function on this element? I'll show you in a minute if you help me with that || Don't worry, found a way around it as well

Comment: trigger a click on this element equals to submit the form, if you create element, but not click on it, that's uselss. I don't know if this is the expecter answer